# theme_table override not working

Tags: theming, hooks

I am trying to override / hook `theme_table` from `theme.inc`.
My theme name is `stat`.
I have added following function to my theme `template.php`.

```
function stat_table($variables) {
  //table logic here
  return $output;
}
```

I have dev env configured with xdebug and while function is 'loaded'/processed when displaying page with table, it is never called.
Original `theme_table` is called instead.
I already tried clearing cache via `drupal_theme_rebuild();`
Using Drupal 7.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?
How can I debug why is the function not called?

Answer (score 0):

use hook_theme_registry_alter.

Example:

```
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['table']['function'] = '_MYMODULE_my_table_theme';
}
```

function _MYMODULE_my_table_theme($variables) {
...
...
}

Comment: I do not have my own module, I am using theme.
This seems to only work for modules.